# Is sudden appearance of poles possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I was thinking about the following scenario:

For $|\epsilon|<1$ let $f_\epsilon(z)$ be a meromorphic function such that

- $f_0(z)$ has a pole at the origin
- for $\epsilon \neq 0$, $f_\epsilon(z)$ is entire.

Is this possible, if we assume the $f_\epsilon$ depends "nicely" on $\epsilon$ (e.g. continuously)? I want to say no, but I can't quite prove this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go with no: if $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ is continuous in $\epsilon$, then the integrals
$$ I_n(\epsilon) := \int_{\lvert z \rvert= r} z^n f_{\epsilon}(z) \, dz \quad n = 0,1,2,\dotsc $$
are

1. continuous functions of $\epsilon$,
2. zero for $\epsilon \neq 0$ by Cauchy's theorem.
3. One of them must be nonzero if $f_0(z)$ has a pole of order $m$ at zero, because it would pick out the coefficient of $z^{-m}$, which must be nonzero by definition.

Since these facts are unreconcilable, I don't think your scenario can occur.